# Color of histogram in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am plotting histogram of a data frame in the following way but I want to color to be blue/anything else. But when I put `color = "blue"` it doesn't change the color and adds additional group on side.

```
> str(neg.all.frame)
'data.frame':   455634 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ probability: num  0.645 0.536 0.365 0.523 0.587 ...
 $ group      : chr  "Unknown/Negative" "Unknown/Negative" "Unknown/Negative" "Unknown/Negative" ...

ggplot(neg.all.frame, aes(colour = "blue", probability, fill = group)) + geom_histogram(alpha = 0.2) +
  xlab("Probability of Being Interested in Fashion") + ylab("Number of People")
```

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: To plot everything in blue, just move the `colour="blue"` out of `aes()` and into `geom_histogram` : `+ geom_histogram(colour = "blue" ...)`

Answer (score 3):

You are passing the string `"blue"` as an aesthetic mapping. What you need to do is to use `fill=blue` as argument within `geom_histogram` instead. Try this:

```
ggplot(neg.all.frame, aes(probability, fill = group)) +    
 geom_histogram(alpha = 0.2, fill = "blue") + 
 xlab("Probability of Being Interested in Fashion") + 
 ylab("Number of People")
```

In grammar of graphics, aesthetic mappings map data to aesthetic features of the visualization. What you are trying to do is not a mapping, but a static change of color.